# Objective C - CLLocationManager crash

Tags: objective-c, core-location

I'm getting reports from users that my app crash upon launch.

So I got the crash report. User is on iOS 4.1.

Crash log below:

```
Thu Nov 17 12:23:49 unknown AppName[1481] <Error>: +[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3e2ee618
Thu Nov 17 12:23:49 unknown AppName[1481] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3e2ee618'
```

Can't seem to see anything wrong with my code, here is what I have

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    // 4.2 and below

    NSLog(@"locationManager error = %@", error);
    if ([error code] != kCLErrorLocationUnknown) {
        [self stopUpdatingLocation:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"Error")];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    // 4.2 & above
    NSLog(@"authorization change = %i", status);
}

- (void)stopUpdatingLocation:(NSString *)state {
    NSLog(@"stop updatinglocation = %@", self.bestEffortAtLocation);
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    locationManager.delegate = nil;
}
```

Please enlight.

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think the error is in the code you listed, somewhere you are trying to access
 `+[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` which is a 4.2+ method, so no surprise with the error message there, you have several options. you can check to respondsToSelector: first, or run the code inside of a @try{} block. either one should keep you from crashing.